# scheduled tasks windows 7 to windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks

I would obviously like laziness to prevail in transferring over my scheduled tasks. The bizarre thing is that I found a portion of the tasks in %SystemRoot%\Tasks and the whole of them in \Windows\System32\Tasks.

The old machine is on windows 7 and the new one is on 8.1. All the machines are networked and when looking from the 8.1 machine it won't recognize the old tasks. Anyone have any luck in transferring tasks over? It seems tedious to create 200 new ones.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that I answered my own question.

From the windows 8.1 task scheduler (run: taskschd.msc) you select Import Task.

Find the location on the other machine: \Windows\System32\Tasks

Change the file extension to all files.

Importing is done one task at a time.